# How to retrieve server alias in Apache config?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a single named virtual host that handles traffic for a bunch of different hostnames.

In the Apache config, I need to create RewriteRules according to the hostname requested by the user. Unfortunately the contents of the `%{SERVER_NAME}` variable always matches the *primary* hostname defined as ServerName in the config, instead of the alias requested by user.

e.g.: I need to serve `site.company.com`, `site2.company.com` and `site3.company.com`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site.company.com
  ServerAlias site?.company.com

  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} pattern
  RewriteRule blah_depending_on_hostname_requested_by_user
</VirtualHost>
```

**Problem**: `%{SERVER_NAME}` is always `site.company.com`, even if user requests one of the aliases such as `site2.company.com`.

How do I solve this? There doesn't seem to be a `%{SERVER_ALIAS}` variable available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean `%{HTTP_HOST}`. That's the exact site name provided by the browser. From [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use
>   a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or
>   %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that one :-( Exactly the one I was looking for. Thanks.